# Read config hash-like data into perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a config file `config.txt` like

```
{sim}{time}{end}=63.1152e6;
{sim}{output}{times}=[2.592e6,31.5576e6,63.1152e6];
{sim}{fluid}{comps}=[ ['H2O','H_2O'], ['CO2','CO_2'],['NACL','NaCl'] ];
```

I would like to read this into a perl hash,

```
my %h=read_config('config.txt');
```

I have checked out module [Config::Hash](http://search.cpan.org/~minimal/Config-Hash-0.920/lib/Config/Hash.pm) , but it does not offer the same input file format.

Comment: First thought, split on equal, then parse each side.

Comment: First identify the file format, then find a parser. If you want to invent a parser, you're either going to have to extrapolate on the "looks like Perl, perhaps it is exactly like Perl", or specify more exactly what the format is like.

Comment: Have you decided on this file format yourself? The design could be made much easier to program with

Comment: @Borodin Yes, what format would you suggest to use?

Comment: @HåkonHægland If you're picking the data format yourself, I'd advise using [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) or [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: @Miller Ok.. maybe I have a look at them if these formats can be read into a Perl hash and can incorporate Perl data structures as array and hashes..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: If all you want to do is to save a Perl data structure to disk and restore it again for a later run of your program, then look at [`FreezeThaw`](https://metacpan.org/module/FreezeThaw) or [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable). But if you want something that you can read and edit independently of program runs then JSON is ideal

Comment: @Borodin I would like to edit the config file yes, I do not consider saving any data structure. Only reading the config file. I see that this was not as easy as I thought in the beginning. But thanks for the good advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can roll your own.  Uses [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aDiver) for traversing the hash, but could do that manually as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Diver qw(DiveVal);

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2;

    my @keys = $key =~ m/[^{}]+/g;

    my $value = eval $val;
    die "Error in line $., '$val': $@" if $@;

    DiveVal(\%hash, @keys) = $value;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash;

__DATA__
{sim}{time}{end}=63.1152e6;
{sim}{output}{times}=[2.592e6,31.5576e6,63.1152e6];
{sim}{fluid}{comps}=[ ['H2O','H_2O'], ['CO2','CO_2'],['NACL','NaCl'] ];
```

Outputs:

```
{
  sim => {
           fluid  => { comps => [["H2O", "H_2O"], ["CO2", "CO_2"], ["NACL", "NaCl"]] },
           output => { times => [2592000, 31557600, 63115200] },
           time   => { end => 63115200 },
         },
}
```

Would be better if you could come up with a way to not utilize [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), but not knowing your data, I can't accurately suggest an alternative.

#### Better Alternative, use a JSON or YAML

If you're picking the data format yourself, I'd advise using [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) or [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) for saving and loading your config data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %config = (
  sim => {
           fluid  => { comps => [["H2O", "H_2O"], ["CO2", "CO_2"], ["NACL", "NaCl"]] },
           output => { times => [2592000, 31557600, 63115200] },
           time   => { end => 63115200 },
         },
);

my $string = encode_json \%config;

## Save the string to a file, and then load below:

my $loaded_config = decode_json $string;

use Data::Dump;
dd $loaded_config;
```

Comment: Great! Can this be used with definitions spanning multiple lines? and interleaved blank lines (to make the config file more readable)?

Comment: This could be adapted to allow definitions spanning multiple lines and to allow blank lines.  But this code in and of itself will not support those features.  This is intended mostly as a proof of concept, but without knowing your full data, I can't predict all the features or edge cases you'd need to support.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.. By the way, when trying to read the config from file, I get error: `Error in line 1, '63.1152e6;': Can't use string ("end") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at /home/fcihh/perl5/lib/perl5/Data/Diver.pm line 129`

Comment: I've reordered the lines so the error checking for the eval will work as intended..

Comment: Thanks Miller.. The JSON works fine too..  But I see there are many issues to consider here, for instance I would like to have comments in the input file.. I need to think more on this. But thanks for the great answer!