# Perl How to build a Dynamic multi level hash lookup

Tags: perl, hash

I have a code block that i use many times with slight variations that i am trying to make into a subroutine.
This code block Completes configuration templates ( router interface, vrf, other network stuff)

It does so by  looking up data in a hash data structure ( called %config_hash) that is built from ingesting a excel file :P. The data that is looked up is in different areas of the hash for different templates.

an example of the current working code is this:

```
my @temp_source_template = @{ clone ($source_template{$switch_int_template}) };

            my %regex_replacements=();                                                  ## hash for holding regex search and replace values, keys are !name! (look in template files) values taken from DCAP
            my @regex_key =();                                                          ## temp array used for whe more then one !name! on a line
            my $find_string='';
            foreach my $line (@temp_source_template){
                my (@regex_key) = ( $line =~ /(\!.*?\!)/g );                        ## match needs to be non greedy thus .*? not .*
                foreach my $hash_refs (@regex_key){
                    my $lookup = $hash_refs =~ s/!//gri;                            ## remove ! from !name! so lookup can be done in DCAP file hash
                    my $excel_lookup = $lookup =~ s/_/ /gri;
                    $regex_replacements{$hash_refs} = $config_hash{'Vlan'}{$inner}{$excel_lookup};          ## lookup DCAP file hash a write value to regex hash
                    if (undef eq $regex_replacements{$hash_refs}){
                        $regex_replacements{$hash_refs} = $config_hash{'Switch'}{$outer}{$excel_lookup};
                    }
                    if (undef eq $regex_replacements{$hash_refs}){
                        $regex_replacements{$hash_refs} = $config_hash{'VRF'}{$middle}{$excel_lookup};
                    }
                    $find_string= $find_string . $hash_refs . '|' ;

                }

            }
```

So this creates a hash (regex_replacements) that contains values to lookup (hash keys in regex_replacements) and values to replace those with (values in regex_replacements). it also builds a string to be used in a regex expression ( $find_string). Different templates will have different hash lookup "paths" ( eg $config_hash{'Switch'}{$outer}{$excel_lookup} ) or in different orders (effectively a most specific match)

for completeness here is the code block that does the regex replacements:

```
foreach my $line (@temp_source_template){
    my (@line_array) = split /(![A-Za-z_]*!)/, $line;
    foreach my $chunk (@line_array){
        my $temp_chunk = $chunk;
        $chunk =~ s/($find_string)/$regex_replacements{$1}/gi;
        if (!($chunk)){
            $chunk = $temp_chunk;
        }
    }
    $line = join ("", @line_array);

    if ($line =~ /\!.*\!/){
        print {$log} " ERROR line has unmatched variables deleting line \"$line\"\n";
        $line ="";
    }
}
```

So I did some searching and i found this:
[Perl: How to turn array into nested hash keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505100/perl-how-to-turn-array-into-nested-hash-keys)
Which is almost exactly what i want but i can't get it to work because my Variable reference is a Hash and its hash variable reference is just "REF" so i get errors for trying to use a hash as a reference.

So I wont post what i have tried as i don't really understand the magic of that link.

But what i am doing is passing to the sub the following

```
            my @temp_source_template = @{ clone ($source_template{$test}) };
        my @search_array = ( ['VRF' ,$middle] , ['Switch' ,$outer]);
        my $find_string, $completed_template = dynamic_regex_replace_fine_string_gen(\%source_config,\@temp_source_template, \@search_array);
```

and i want returned the $find_string and the regex_replacements hash ref. It should be noted that in the sub i need to append onto the end of the elements of @search array the value of $excel_lookup.

The bit that i dont understand how to do is build the variable level hash lookup.

Comment: Turning your incomplete snippets into [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us to help you.

Comment: *"but i can't get it to work because my Variable reference is a Hash"*: What variable reference are you talking about? Do you mean `\%source_config`?

Comment: I think i have over complicated things, what i want to do is pass to a sub routine an array where each element is a path in a hash. in the subroutine i want to uses those element to do a lookup in the hash. So @array [ '$level1' , '$level2' , '$level3' , '$level n'] and in the sub effective do print " $hash{$level1}{$level2}{$level3} but it needs to be dynamic as i dont know how many levels i will need to go down to access the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try use [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) it provides a simple access to elements of deeply nested structures.

For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Diver qw(Dive);

my $hash = { a => { b => 1, c => { d => 2 }}};
my $keys = [[ 'a', 'b'], ['a','c','d']];
lookup_keys( $hash, $keys );

sub lookup_keys {
    my ( $hash, $keys ) = @_;

    for my $key ( @$keys ) {
        my $value = Dive( $hash, @$key );
        say $value;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1
2
```

**See Also**:

- [Creating hash of hash dynamically in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36033603/2173773)
- [Read config hash-like data into perl hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24396250/2173773)

Comment: This is exactly what i want is there any elegant methods to do this without having to install a rather obscure package?

Comment: @Andrew you could always read the code and see if you can recreate it. But why bother if someone else already built and tested it for you?  ;)